# If / Else statement with curly braces

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, search, curly-braces

I'm trying to create a function with two arguments, one for an array (ary) and the second for an name that will be search inside the array.

However, I don't understand why the first code does not work and the second does.

Can someone explain it, please?

```
// wrong code
var fruit = ['banana', 'apple', 'cherry', 'watermelon'];
var food = ['pizza', 'rice', 'cheese', 'potato'];
var search = function(ary, name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        if (name == ary[i]) {
            return name + " was found!";
        } else {
            return name + " was not found";
        }
    }
};
search(food, 'potato');
//"potato was not found"


// right code
var fruit = ['banana', 'apple', 'cherry', 'watermelon'];
var food = ['pizza', 'rice', 'cheese', 'potato'];
var search = function(ary, name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++)
        if (name == ary[i]) 
            return name + " was found!";
    return name + " was not found";
};

search(food, 'potato');
//"potato was found!"
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the wrong code the "was not found" happens when checking the first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++)
    if (name == ary[i]) 
        return name + " was found!";
return name + " was not found";
```

is the same as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    if (name == ary[i]) {
        return name + " was found!";
    }
}
return name + " was not found";
```

It return `false` after looping over all the items in the array. In the wrong code you provided, It only checks if the first item is equal to `name` because inside the loop you return no matter if it was found or not (so if the first item is equal to `name` it will return `true`, if not it will return `false`) So the items from index `1` won't be checked because the function has already returned.

---

**NOTE:** you can use the default search funtion in JS: `indexOf` like this:

```
var search = function(ary, name) {
    if(ary.indexOf(name) != -1) // index is -1 (not valid) then it's not found
        return name + " was found";
    else
        return name + " was not found";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you will return on the first match failure so after it fails to match the first item of the array, it will return from the function.

So the part in the else block, should be moved outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the first function, uou immediately return after one iteration; you don't wait for the entire array to loop through ; I bet the first element of the array is 'found'.

So for your first function, these WILL be found:

```
search(fruit, 'banana');
search(food, 'pizza');
```

but no others.

In the second one, returning 'not found' happens only if the entire array has been looped through without a match being found , ie when it exits the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem.

In the first code segment, you are returning false in the else statement. This means that the first time through the loop, you will EITHER return true or false. It only  checks the first item.

Answer (score 1):

In your first version, the `else` is within the `for` loop, so the function will always return either "was found" or "was not found" in its first iteration.  The loop will never reach its second iteration.

In your second version, the `else` is not part of the `for` loop body, so it runs only after the loop finishes (running all its iterations) without finding a match.